# how to set the condition in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

Each ticket office is allowed a queue.

Its maximum length is QueueCapacity1 and QueueCapacity2 installed 10 people.

When a new application is received, its processing is performed
order:

- if a client of the first type arrives and the queue to the first cash desk is not complete, then the customer is put into this queue, otherwise, if the queue is not full to the 2 ticket offices, it goes to the queue to the cashier №2;
- if both queues are full, then the client proceeds to the ticket machine;
- if a second type client arrives and the queue to the second ticket office is not complete, the client "Placed" there, otherwise it goes to the vending machine to purchase a ticket.

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: You haven't actually specified what your question is, how your screenshot relates to what you have attempted (and how the Services / Delays / SelectOutputs relate to your 'specification', and how you currently setup your SelectOutputs), and where you have problems. As Felipe says in his answer we can make sensible guesses on this, but it would be better if you update your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? Not sure if I understood your question, but this is how I would set a condition using selectOutput5 to solver your problem.

[image: model]

[image: selectOutput5]

Comment: Can you help with these tasks, please?
1. if both queues are full, then the client proceeds to the ticket machine;
2.if a second type client arrives and the queue to the second ticket office is not complete, the client "Placed" there, otherwise it goes to the vending machine to purchase a ticket.

Comment: I am very grateful to you. You helped me a lot))))

Comment: I still have a question. In the picture above, Type1, is this?

Comment: Type1 is your agent type coming from source1, your agent coming from source2 should be of a different type... at least that is what I got from your question